# ElasticSearch: how to perform search across multiple fields using Java High Level REST Client?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking at this tutorial and it describes how ES search could be executed against an index, but the search is done only using one field of each document:

`SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "kimchy"));`

I would like to perform my search against multiple fields: like user name, display name, email etc.

Should I use Multi-Search API to achieve it? 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-multi-search.html

Comment: Try this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.6/multimatch.html. You can specify multiple parameters comma separated.

Comment: I was specifically asking about how that can be done using Java High-Level Rest Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MultiMatchQueryBuilder` allows to do it, thanks to Abhay for helping me to find the proper solution.

https://snapshots.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.4.0-SNAPSHOT/org/elasticsearch/index/query/MultiMatchQueryBuilder.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: Glad, I could help you.